# Getting an error in android studio while launching or building app "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'"?

Tags: android, gradle, building, aapt2

My android studio was working perfect and well after I newly installed in my new windows.
I opened android studio about 15 days later (Now) and updated some dependencies. I get this error while building project or launching the app in virtual/physical device?

Please anyone help me in this case, it is very important for me!

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.6.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\2e1BQZKqdp2CV3QV5nUEsqSg1ygegLmqRygj\transformed\appcompat-1.6.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-18.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\914a48735981d496ffe7a0bf3561820a\transformed\play-services-base-18.1.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-18.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\914a48735981d496ffe7a0bf3561820a\transformed\play-services-base-18.1.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-18.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\914a48735981d496ffe7a0bf3561820a\transformed\play-services-base-18.1.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.9.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\adad71850fc2705f50aed16a5c9c1998\transformed\core-1.9.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform ambilwarna-2.0.1.aar (com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\rafiq\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5363d17d57f604507da9e04093fd2f44\transformed\ambilwarna-2.0.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-8.1.1-10154469-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
           Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I invalided all caches but not worked.
I restarted android studio many times but not worked.

Comment: what are the dependencies you've updated ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be hidden in this line in your output:

> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.

So, please check if you have installed all required dependencies.